# BizTalk 2016 - No more BtsControl ? How to stop a given BizTalk application by script?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am in the process to migrate an old BTS 2006 application in BTS 2016.

It works fine but I have a problem with CI script migration using Jenkins. My Jenkins script call BtsControl command to stop a given BizTalk application. BTSControl.exe was a BizTalk Application Deployment Tool for Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006, described as the companion tool to BTSTask.exe. It was an open source development and I don't find its equivalent in BizTalk 2016.

So how can I stop a given BizTalk application with BizTalk 2016 (by script, of course)?

Comment: How about Powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/applicationmanager-biztalk-server-sample#windows-powershell-script-example

Comment: I will try it; thanks !